# Problems with generics within Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm trying to do a generic class, but I can not get "funTestInterface" to stop asking for "Nothing", does anyone know why this can happen? Thank you!

```
package main

interface ITest<S> {
    fun funTestInterface(param: S): S
}

class GeneralClass {
    fun otro(param: ITest<*>, secondParam: Any) {
        param.funTestInterface(secondParam)
    }
}

class ImplementedClass : ITest<String> {

    override fun funTestInterface(param: String): String {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}

fun main() {
    val a = GeneralClass()

    a.otro(ImplementedClass(), "")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [star-projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) here. You can use `param` with star projection to only safely read values from it (you can use it as an output type), but in your case the star is treat as input type. The star in compilation is treat as type `Nothing` which is not equivalent to `Any`. Said that, you can't use `Any` as an input to  `funTestInterface`.

You can simply resolve that by generifying your `GeneralClass.otro()` function:

```
fun <T> otro(param: ITest<T>, secondParam: T) {
    param.funTestInterface(secondParam)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what I needed! and very good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

GeneralClass  should be

```
class GeneralClass {
fun otro(param: ITest<String>, secondParam: Any) {
    param.funTestInterface(secondParam as String)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but I needed something more generic :D